# About Big O Notations and Complexity

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm currently learning Big O Notations, but I'm kinda confused with time/iterations calculation according to different complexities.

I made up this problem:

> An algorithm that goes through all possible solutions takes 10^(-7) seconds with each test.
>   If the number of solutions are the following functions: logn, n, nlog. n^2, what's the maximum n I can calculate in, for example, less than 1 second?

What I though about (for case logn) was 10^-7 times logn must take less than 1 second:

```
10^(-7) * logn < 1 <=> n = 10^(1/10^-7)
```

Incredibly big (If it's not wrong, oh damn --'). But what about n^2 ?

```
10^(-7) * n^2 < 1 <=> n = square_root(1/10^-7)
```

But how can the number of solutions in n^2 case be less than the number in n, if the complexity is bigger? This is confusing me...?

Comment: It should be noted that for programming, `log N` almost always in base 2 rather than base 10 and should really be treated as such unless a different base is indicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news first there is nothing "wrong" with the result of your calculation.

Naturally if the complexity of an algirithm is higher (like O(n^2) complexity is higher than O(log n)), the size of the problem you are still able to handle in "acceptable" time will be smaller, in total accordance to your calculation.

Nevertheless the example  seems a bit twisted and I have to admit, I didn't completely understand the purpose, you invented the 10^-7 factor for and thus suspect, you didn't get the concept of the O notation right.

Essentially the main idea of the O notation is, that you don't care about any linear factors (like the 10^7 factor you invented in your calculation) in comparing two algorithms, but only about how fast computation time grows with the size of the problem, as constant (and thus not growing) factors sooner or later will become irrelevant compared to the growth in computation time due to the problem size.

Going by example:

With the O(n^2) algorithm A, taking the time t=2*n^2 milliseconds and the O(log n) algorithm B, taking t=200*log(n) millliseconds on a specific machine for given problem size nr things will look as follows:

For a very small problem, say n=10, Algorithm A might be faster than Algorithm B:

```
2*10^2 = 2*100 = 200 ms
400*log10 = 400*1 = 400 ms
```

But with growing problem size, say n=100, Algorithm B will sooner or later overtake Algorithm A in speed:

```
2*100^2 = 2*10,000 = 20,000 ms
400*log100 = 400*2 = 800 ms
```

While for even bigger problem sizes, say n=1,000,000, waiting for A to complete might take a lot of patience.

```
2*1,000,000^2 = 2*10^12 ms = 2*10^9 s = 33333333 min = 555555 h = 23148 days = 63 years
```

Algorithm B might still operate in acceptable time.

```
400*log1,000,000 = 400*6 = 2,400 ms = 2.4 s
```

As the constant factor plays an ever smaller role with growing problem size, for bigger and bigger problems it becomes more and more irrelevant and is therefore (together with terms of lower order, that follow the same rule) left out in the O notation.

Thus the "right" way to look at complexities given in O notation is not trying to look at fixed values for fixed n or even reinvent constant factors and additional terms of lower order already abstracted away, but to look how fast computation time grows with problem size.

So, again going by example the "right" way to look at complexity of O(n^2) and O(log10) would be to compare their growth.

If the problem size grows by a factor of 10 Algorithm A's computation time will rise by a factor of 100, thus taking 100 times as long as before, as:

```
(n*10)^2 = n^2 * 10^2 = n^2 * 100
```

While Algorithm B's computation time will just grow by a constant ammount, as:

```
log(n*10) = log(n) + log(10) = log(n) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

"This is bad on so many levels."

First off, O(f(n)) is not the same as f(n).

Complexity is typically used to represent the *time* it takes to solve a problem, as a function of the *size* of the input.

*Of course* if you can solve more problems in the same amount of time using X vs Y, X will solve more problems in a fixed amount of time than Y.  But since you're not using the term complexity in the right way, it is no surprise you get a (seemingly) paradoxical answer.

Comment: Reformulated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You just upper bounded your algorithm to a real world time of 10^(-7) seconds, which implies that your algorithm will guarantee to finish, for all complexities, in 10^(-7) seconds.

Let's refrain from discussing if this is possible in reality. But since you just defined your algorithm to go through *all possible solutions* in 10^(-7), it means no matter what n is, it will finish in that time. So your n is positive infinity.

Besides, I don't think you should use big O to denote *the number of solutions*.